# Angular Url-template throws The resource cannot be found

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying implement pagination on my page and i am getting the following error.

```
angular.min.js:87 GET http://localhost:56485/Areas/EVerify/Views/EVerify/dirPagination.tpl.html 404 (Not Found)
```

js file :

```
var EVerifyModule = angular.module('EVerifyModule', ['angularFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

                           var EmployeeInfo = [ {
                            "name": "Daniel Cho",
                            "hireDate": "03/11/2016",
                            "responseDate": "03/13/2016",
                            "submitDate": "03/12/2016",
                            "authStatus": "Authorized",
                            "caseSatus": "Closed",
                            "phone": "+1 (213) 382-1115",
                            "authorized": true
                        }
    ];

                           $scope.EmployeeInfo = EmployeeInfo;

                            function initConfigurationClosedCases() {
                                sessionStorage.ModuleSelected = 'Closed Cases';
                                LoadMenuInformation();
                            }

                           }]);
```

in the cshtml :

```
   <div ng-controller="OtherController" class="other-controller">
                                <small>this is in "OtherController"</small>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="/Areas/EVerify/Views/EVerify/dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following element in your layout's `<head>`

```
<base href="@Url.Content("~")">
```

and also omit the slash `/` when referring to a file, ie:

```
template-url="Areas/...
```

Finally, I'm suggesting to create a folder in the root of your project and host your angular `.js` and `.html` files there. There is a chance that the server blocks request towards static files within the `Areas` folder.